# On an exercise on restrictions of functions in a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, functions

I rewrite the text of an exercise:

Given $X$ and $Y$ topological spaces and a family of subsets $\{A_i \}_{i \in I}$ of $X$ s.t. $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ .

Let $\{ f_i : A_i \rightarrow Y \}_{i \in I}$ be a family of continuous function such that $f_{i\mid A_i \cap A_j} = f_{j\mid A_i \cap A_j}$

then

1. Assuming every $A$ is open  in $X$ prove that there exist one and only one continuous $f_i : X \rightarrow Y$ s.t. $f_{|A_i} = f_i$.
2. Assuming every $A$ is closed  in $X$ is it possible to prove that there exist one and only one continuous $f_i : X \rightarrow Y$ s.t. $f_{|A_i} = f_i$?

I don't really get the first question because it seems to me it is possible to construct different functions $f_k$ that still satisfy $f_{|A_i} = f_k$, I suspect I am not using the fact that the $A$ are all open.

Would someone be so kind as to show me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in X$ be an arbitrary point. Let's denote by $I_x=\{i\in I: x\in A_i\}.$ So, we define $f(x)=f_i(x)$ for some (any) $i\in I_x.$ This function is well-defined, since if $j\in I_x,$ $j\ne i,$ then $f_j(x)=f_i(x),$ because $f_{i|A_i \cap A_j} = f_{j|A_i \cap A_j}.$

So, there exist one and only one function $f:X\to Y$ such that $f_{|A_i} = f_i, \forall i \in I.$ (Note that we have only used that $X = \cup_{i \in I} A_i$ and not the fact of being closed or open.)

**Hint for continuity**

If we assume that the $A_i's$ are open then we have that $f$ is continuous. Let $x\in X$ be an arbitrary point. There exists $i$ such that $x\in A_i.$ Use that $f_{|A_i} = f_i$ and that $f_i$ is continuous to show continuity of $f$ at $x.$

Can you think of a non-continuous function if the $A'i$ are closed? For example, if you consider $X=[0,1]$ with the Euclidean topoloty and $A_i$ consists of only one point, for each $i?$

Comment: Extended hint: If the $A_i$ are closed and the covering $(A_i)_i$ is locally finite, then we do get continuity

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I am a bit unsure from where we got uniqueness, I understand now that the exercise asks to prove the existence of one unique continuous function. By defining the function as you did it certainly satisfies $f_{i|A_i \cap A_j} = f_{j|A_i \cap A_j}$ and $f_{|A_i} = f_i, \forall i \in I.$ but could you be more explicit on uniqueness?  Also please tell me if I am misunderstanding what you did, thanks again.

Comment: @Monolite unicity is clear, and always true (regardless of what the $A_i$ are, as long as they cover). Why: we want to find $f(x)$ for some $x$. This $x$ is already in some $A_i$ (they cover), so we have to give it the value $f_i(x)$ (because $f|A_i$ must equal $f$). If $x \in A_j$ as well, then $f_i$ and $f_j$ agree on $x$, because $x \in A_i \cap A_j$, and the other condition is used. So there is no choice in defining $f(x)$. Hence unicity.

Comment: Imagine you have two different functions $f$ and $g$. Then there exist $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\ne g(x).$ But, if $x\in A_i$ it must be $f(x)=f_i(x)=g(x).$ This contradicts the initial assumption.